# how to change the shape of the image tensor? is it doable?

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

this is my code

```
with tf.Session(config=tf_config) as sess:
    image_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')

    detection_boxes = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')
    detection_scores = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
    detection_classes = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')
    num_detections = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0')

    (boxes, scores, classes, num) = sess.run( [detection_boxes, detection_scores, detection_classes, num_detections],feed_dict={image_tensor: img[None, ...]})
```

i want to run the object detection in Gray frames to reduce the detection time,for that i need to change the shape of the image_tensor to (1,?,?,1), which has the shape of (1,?,?,3). is it possible to change the shape and am i asking the right question?

Answer (score 0):

It is totally possible to reshape Tensor to the any shape if they got same dimension size.

For example, you have image_tensor shape (1, A, B, 1).

Now, you want to reshape it to the (1, C, D, 3).

To do complete this, you have to set size between two different tensor.

If 1*A*B*1 and 1*C*D*3 are same size, it is possible to change tensor shape.

`a = torch.Tensor(1, 3, 3, 1)`

`b = a.reshape(1,3,1,3)`

now Tensor b is shape of (1, 3, 1, 3).